# How can you add a TouchGridPanel to a Panel in Sencha 2?

Tags: grid, dataview, sencha-touch-2

I'm currently using the Sencha Ext.ux.TouchGridPanel, and I need to know how to add it to a Panel dynamically. Currently, I set up a store, then use a function to generate the Panel. I then use

```
myPanel.add(myTouchGridPanel);
```

This displays the toolbar and headings of the Panel, but not any of the information within it. Making the TouchGridPanel fullscreen works, but then the animations are sloppy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the component is working correctly, perhaps the panel you are inserting it into is not the size you expect it to be?

Or maybe the GridPanel is not stretching to the size of the panel, in which case, you should add a `fit` or `card` layout to the panel, so it fits to the size of that panel.

If neither of these two things work, I suggest you open up web inspector and look at the dom of your panel - and see what the size of it is, and if the grid is actually being added to it or not.